# Object inside function not getting executed when calling function from another component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Apologies for not being able to title my question properly.
Let me explain my issue properly.
I have 2 Components say A and B.
In B I have a function `saveIndCustData` which emits and saves data.

```
export class CustomerformComponent implements OnInit {
@Output()
savedIndCustomer: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
saveIndCustData() {
const savedIndCustomer = {
  prefix: this.prefix,
  nameType: this.indCustNameType,
  firstName: this.firstName,
  middleNAme: this.middleName,
  lastName: this.lastName,
  gender: this.gender,
  dateOfBirth: this.parseDate(this.dateOfBirth.toString()),
  citizenship: this.citizenship
};

this.savedIndCustomer.emit(savedIndCustomer);
this.snackbar.open('Customer Info Saved,Click on Next', 'Close', {
  duration: 5000
});
}
}
```

I am now calling the function from component A.

```
import { CustomerformComponent } from './forms/customerform/customerform.component';
constructor(private custComp: CustomerformComponent) {}
saveCustomerForm(): void {
this.custComp.saveIndCustData();
}
```

I emit the data into a service class

```
@Output()
savedIndCustomer: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Service Class

```
public addDynamiIndCustomerComponent() {
const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CustomerformComponent);
const component = factory.create(this.rootViewContainer.parentInjector);
component.instance.savedIndCustomer.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  // Insert Individual Customer Type
  this.custFullDetails.customerType = 'individual';
  this.custFullDetails.individualCustomer.dateOfBirth = data.dateOfBirth;
  this.custFullDetails.individualCustomer.citizenship = data.citizenship;
  this.custFullDetails.individualCustomer.gender = data.gender;
  this.custFullDetails.individualCustomer.individualName.push({
    prefix: data.prefix,
    firstName: data.firstName,
    middleName: data.middleName,
    lastName: data.lastName,
    agreementId: data.agreementId,
    nameType: data.nameType
  });
  console.log(this.custFullDetails.individualCustomer);
});
this.rootViewContainer.insert(component.hostView);
}
```

My issue is if I invoke the `saveIndCustData` function from component B it pushes data into array `const savedIndCustomer{ ... }` and calls the service class.
However when I invoke the same function from component A it doesn't invoke the `const savedIndCustomer{ ... }` method inside `saveIndCustData()` function and service class method does not save data in array but it simply shows the  snakbar.
What is the issue?

Comment: Your code structure is not standard. You cannot inject a component in another component. Also, you are trying to access the component directly in the service, which is not a good approach.

Comment: So can you tell me proper way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you put the component B inside the html of component A, so you should make a reference for the component B like this

A.component.html:

```
...
    <B #bcmp></B>
...
```

and inject it in A.component.ts using @ViewChild like this

A.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'A',
    templateUrl: './A.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./A.component.scss']
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild("bcmp") bcmp : B
    ngOnInit(): void {
        // by this way you can use any method existant in B component
        this.bcmp.saveIndCustData();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not referencing html of Comp B in comp A. I just want to invoke the function from component A.